# How can I define the excel page layout while using the xlswrite command in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm working in MATLAB and use the `xlswrite` command to write into an excel file.
This is the command I use:

```
xlswrite([PathName 'FileName.xls'],DATA,'A2');
```

The command create the excel file with the new sheet A2, but this sheet ordered in excel from right to left, I want it to be from left to right.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have matlab open right know but this should work:

You can also edit a .xls file using ActiveX:

```
OBJ         = actxserver ( 'Excel.Application' ); % Create an Excel object.
OBJ.Visible = 1; 
WB          = OBJ.Workbooks; 
WB_OBJ      = WB.Open('myfile.xls'); Create a workbook object.
SHEETS      = WB_OBJ.Sheets; % Object containing all sheets
NBR         = SHEETS.Count; % # of sheets
```

Now for example if you want to inverte the sheets position:

```
for ii = 1:NBR
    S{ii} = get(SHEETS, 'Item', ii ); % Get sheet #1
end

S = fliplr(S);

WB_OBJ.Save; % Save workbook
WB_OBJ.Close(false); % Close workbook

OBJ.Quit % close Excel in MATLAB
OBJ.delete % Delete the server object.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But - where in the attached code you define the page layout direction?